# Why adding stopPropagation() on container of React Select completely stops React Select event?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I simply want to stop event bubbling of arrows and enter keys while leaving react select's event untouched. So I put `event.stopPropagation()` on the **container** of the react select. But it completely hinders react select's default functionalities. Shouldn't the event bubble up from child to parent?

I've uploaded the source [here](http://www.filedropper.com/sandbox4)

Just run

```
npm install
npm start
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CreatableSelect  from "react-select/lib/Creatable"

const colourOptions = [
    { value: 'red', label: 'Red' },
    { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue' },
    { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow' }
]

class CustomCreatableSelect extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.Ref.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            let key = event.which || event.keyCode
            if (key === 37 || key === 38 || key === 39 || key === 40 || key === 13) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                console.log("onKeyDown "+key);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref = { ref => { this.Ref = ref }}> 
                <CreatableSelect
                    onChange                = {this.handleChange}
                    options                 = {colourOptions}
                    formatCreateLabel       = {this.formatCreate}
                    createOptionPosition    = {"first"}
                    ref                     = { ref => { this.SelectRef = ref }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomCreatableSelect
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need use `event.preventDefault()`instead `event.stopPropagation();`

`Event.preventDefault()` - Cancels an event if it is canceled, without stopping further propagation of this event.

The `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Comment: I need to stop the propagation because in my real use case it will trigger another unwanted event. This case above is just an example.

Comment: event.preventDefault() - Cancels an event if it is canceled, without stopping further propagation of this event.

Comment: Nope, I've tried it. What I want is stopping the further propagation, and you suggest to cancel the event and let it propagates instead? That's the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.